# Few basic questions on flex/AS

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, mxml, mxmlc

Guys i have struggling with flex since a day or two.I havent found a nice short tutorials.Actually i  also have been struggling with FLEX IDE too.Please indicate a nice good tutorials for this
I basically have questions like

- Cannot use Alert in AS
- Including  a AS file in mxml file
- org.com.structure and the as file in it.Why do we need to say `pacakage org.com` inside the as file

Comment: if you have a few weeks you should get a copy of this book and read it instead of dealing with online tutorials:  http://www.amazon.com/Adobe-Flex-Training-Michael-Labriola/dp/0321660501/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1293109723&sr=8-1

Answer (score 3):

- You can use flex Alert class. In pure AS, unlike JavaScript, there is no alert().
- `<mx:Script source="script.as"/>`. But script.as will not know about MXML file, it's better to use class defined in as file as a control in MXML.
- Because packages are compiler-enforced design decision, and who we are to discuss it.

Answer (score 3):

Flex in a week!

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html

This video series helped me a lot..